# No menu LMDE Betsy

Tags: debian, mate-desktop, lmde

I just ran an update on LMDE Betsy MATE. After restart I can neither see the start menu or the icons on the desktop. I can only press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> to restart of poweroff.

I can not even start the terminal using alt+f2. I can however, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> to boot into the command line.

I am using the MSI GX70 with 16gb RAM and ATI 8650G

How do I recover the original GUI?